# I cannot create Rails app on Netbeans 7.0. It hangs at the point 25%

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

My development env. is,
Win7 Ultimate
Ruby 1.9.2p180
Rails 3.0.9
Gem 1.8.5
sqlite3 and mysql2 gems are installed
My IDE is netbeans 7.0. ruby plugin for netbeans 7.0 is installed. i want to create a new rails app thru netbeans. but it hangs at the process of 25%.  does someone hit the same issue? Is there a solution?

From the output, i can see the rails app file structures are created.

I know some of you may suggest me to use linux to develop rails app. that's an option. but i am newer to linux. i'd like to use win7 at present.

i can create rails app and start it on command line.

Comment: even if you want to use win, there is still no need to use NetBeans. does it work if you use the commandline?

Comment: This isn't a support forum for Netbeans. Try their support.

Comment: Here's a link for you: http://forums.netbeans.org/ruby-users.html

Comment: same problem mate, how did you solved that?

Answer (score 2):

Create the Rails application outside of Netbeans. Then open the folder with Netbeans. Prior to Netbeans 7, which drops native support for Ruby, you could open a Rails directory in Netbeans and it would use the directory & Rails configuration to setup your project for you. I assume the folks that are carrying on the Ruby plugin support for Netbeans 7 have kept that capability.

As others have suggested Linux is an easier to setup for Rails development than Windows, at least in my experience. If you want to stay on Windows I suggest checking out  [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/). There may be an issue with your Rails setup that is hanging, and not necessarily Netbeans.

**Updated**
I have seen this happen when Netbeans is happily awaiting input. When you create the project in Netbeans it executes rails new APP underneath and if that process asks a question, then Netbeans will hang. Check the Netbeans output window (if it's open). You can verify this by creating the rails app on the command line. Once you do that, open the directory with Netbeans and it should recognize the project as a Rails project.

Comment: Now, i turned to use net beans 6.9.1. It also becomes hung at 25%.
after that, i killed net beans process. restart netbeans 6.9.1, at least, it can load the failed new rails project. Other functions of netbeans 6.9.1 work fine. 
It's ok for me to use net beans 6.9.1 at present.

thanks veryone

Comment: Were you able to successfuly create a project outside of netbeans? If not, then there's probably a problem with your Ruby/Rails install. Also, remember to check out the "output" window on Netbeans. It may be asking you a quesiton and waiting for a response.